# C# XP Sound QuickFix

Tags: c#, audio, windows-xp, playback

I have this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(FireAttackProc), fireResult);
```

and FireAttackProc:

```
    private void FireAttackProc(Object stateInfo)
    {
        // Process Attack/Fire (local)
        lock (_procLock)
        {
            // build status message
            String status = "(Away vs. Home)";

            // get Fire Result state info
            FireResult fireResult = (FireResult)stateInfo;

            // update home grid with attack information
            GameModel.HomeCellStatusSet(fireResult.FireGridLocation, Cell.cellState.Lock);
            this.Invoke(new Action(delegate() { RefreshHomeGrid(); }));

            status = status + "(Attack Coordinate: (" + GameModel.alphaCoords(fireResult.FireGridLocation.Column) +
                "," + fireResult.FireGridLocation.Row + "))(Result: ";

            // play audio data if true
            if (audio)
            {
                String Letters;

                Stream stream;
                SoundPlayer player;

                Letters = GameModel.alphaCoords(fireResult.FireGridLocation.Column);
                stream = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("_" + Letters);
                player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(stream);
                player.PlaySync();


                Letters = fireResult.FireGridLocation.Row.ToString();
                stream = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("__" + Letters);
                player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(stream);
                player.PlaySync();

                stream.Dispose();
                player.Dispose();
            }

            if (audio)
            {
                SoundPlayer fire = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.fire);
                fire.PlaySync();
                fire.Dispose();
            }

            // deal with hit/miss
            switch (fireResult.Hit)
            {
                case true:
                    this.Invoke(new Action(delegate()
                    {
                        GameModel.HomeCellStatusSet(fireResult.FireGridLocation, Cell.cellState.Hit);
                        status = status + "(Hit)";
                    }));

                    if (audio)
                    {
                        SoundPlayer hit = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.firehit);
                        hit.PlaySync();
                        hit.Dispose();

                    }
                    break;

                case false:
                    this.Invoke(new Action(delegate() 
                    {
                        GameModel.HomeCellStatusSet(fireResult.FireGridLocation, Cell.cellState.Miss);
                        status = status + "(Miss)";
                    }));

                    GameModel.PlayerNextTurn = NietzscheBattleshipsGameModel.GamePlayers.Home;

                    if (audio)
                    {
                        SoundPlayer miss = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.firemiss);
                        miss.PlaySync();
                        miss.Dispose();
                    }
                    break;
            }

            // refresh home grid with updated data
            this.Invoke(new Action(delegate() { RefreshHomeGrid(); }));

            GameToolStripStatusLabel.Text = status + ")";

            // deal with ship destroyed
            if (fireResult.ShipDestroyed)
            {
                status = status + "(Destroyed: " + GameModel.getShipDescription(fireResult.DestroyedShipType) + ")";

                if (audio)
                {
                    Stream stream;
                    SoundPlayer player;

                    stream = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("_home");
                    player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(stream);
                    player.PlaySync();
                    player.Dispose();
                    stream.Dispose();

                    string ShipID = fireResult.DestroyedShipType.ToString();
                    stream = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("_" + ShipID);
                    player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(stream);
                    player.PlaySync();
                    player.Dispose();
                    stream.Dispose();

                    stream = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("_destroyed");
                    player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(stream);
                    player.PlaySync();
                    player.Dispose();
                    stream.Dispose();
                }
            }

            // deal with win condition
            if (fireResult.Win)
            {
                if (audio)
                {
                    Stream stream;
                    SoundPlayer player;

                    stream = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("_home");
                    player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(stream);
                    player.PlaySync();
                    player.Dispose();

                    stream = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("_loses");
                    player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(stream);
                    player.PlaySync();
                    player.Dispose();
                }

                GameModel.gameContracts = new GameContracts();
            }

            // update status message
            if (fireResult.Hit)
            {
                if (!fireResult.Win)
                {
                    status = status + "(Turn: Away)";

                    LockGUIControls();
                }
            }

            // deal with turn logic
            if (GameModel.PlayerNextTurn == NietzscheBattleshipsGameModel.GamePlayers.Home)
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action(delegate()
                {
                    if (!fireResult.Win)
                    {
                        status = status + "(Turn: Home)";

                        AwayTableLayoutPanel.Enabled = true;
                    }
                }));
            }

            // deal with win condition
            if (fireResult.Win)
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action(delegate()
                {
                    status = status + "(Game: Home Loses)";

                    CancelToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                    NewToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                    LockGUIControls();
                }));
            }

            // display completed status message
            GameToolStripStatusLabel.Text = status + ")";
        }
    }
```

The issue is this:

Under Vista/win7 the sound clips in the FireAttackProc plays.

But under XP the logic contained within FireAttackProc gets executed but none of the sound clips play.

Is there a quick solution to this so the sound will play under XP?

I ask for a quick solution because i am happy being able to execute fully in Vista/Win7 but would be great if there was a quick solution so it would be XP compitable also.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you verify that the Letters variable always contains something that corresponds to a sound resource name _Letters?

Comment: What happens if you remove (at least temporarily) the lock()-block? It seems strange that you are locking so MUCH code on _procLock. It's possible that this lock is inhibiting some things you didn't intend :-)

Comment: @Bob: yes i have checked that and there are no issues there. the lock() is there to implement logical flow i.e. not process anything else while already processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SoundPlayer is really quite lackluster, but that's all .NET 2.0 comes with. Try my player (based on [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MP3Example.aspx)) instead, which uses MCI to play sounds:

http://pastebin.com/aVDWBJ45

You can use other audio codecs (such as MP3), and you only have to load the file once (and not every time you attack, which incurs a delay). And you can play sounds asynchronously without creating additional threads.

It is really easy to use. Simply create a new `QueuedSamplesPlayer` with a generic argument of whatever you'd like to identify sounds (such as an `enum`, a `string` or an `int`). Use the `AddSample` method to load all your sounds on startup. Then use `Play` or `PlayAsync` to play the file synchronously or asynchronously, respectively.

You can call `PlayAsync` multiple times and the sounds will play in order, one after another (without blocking your current thread). You can even call `PlayAsync` while sound is playing, and it will be added to the sound queue to be played. When all sounds have finished playing, a QueueEmpty event will be raised.

This player has been tested on Windows XP, Vista and 7.